# request.getparameter no recupera el valor y llega null al Servlet desde el JSF

Tags: jsf, null

Acudo a su gran ayuda ya que he intentado varias cosas y aun sigo con el error

mi problema radica en que deseo enviar desde mi pagina xhtml un parámetro que agregue a un método que le llega a mi controller de la vista, el método es generarVisualizacionPdfCartaLaboral agregue como parámetro vin.codigoEmpresa

```html
<p:column headerText="#{msgs.view}">
  <div style="text-align: center;">
    <p:commandButton action="#{cartaLaboralMB.generarVisualizacionPdfCartaLaboral(vin.codigo,vin.codigoEmpresa)}" ajax="false" alt="imprimir" icon="fa fa-fw fa-file-text">
    </p:commandButton>
  </div>
</p:column>
```

el método del controller es

```
public String generarVisualizacionPdfCartaLaboral(String codVin, String codigoEmpre) {
    codigoVinculacion = codVin;
    codigoEmpresa = codigoEmpre;
    return "cartaLaboralPdf";
}
```

estas son las propiedades de mi parámetro

```
private String codigoEmpresa =  null;

public String getCodigoEmpresa() {
    return codigoEmpresa;
}

public void setCodigoEmpresa(String codigoEmpresa) {
    this.codigoEmpresa = codigoEmpresa;
}
```

cuando se envía el valor del parámetro al servlet llega null y no entiendo el porque

este es el servlet

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, AplicacionExcepcion {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try {
        String codigoVinculacion = request.getParameter("codigoVinculacion");
        String codigoEmpresa = request.getParameter("codigoEmpresa");
        String banderaMensaje = request.getParameter("banderaMensaje");

        System.out.println("Parametro codigo empresa" + codigoEmpresa);

        String rutaImagenes = getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/");
        byte[] reporte = this.sieteWebFachada.generarReporteCartaLaboral(codigoVinculacion,
                FormatoReporteEnum.REPORTE_PDF, rutaImagenes);
        ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        response.reset();
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition",
                "inline;  filename=\"Carta_Laboral_" + codigoVinculacion
                + ".pdf\"");
        servletOutputStream.write(reporte);
        servletOutputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException | AplicacionExcepcion ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CartaLaboralMB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        FacesUtils.addErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

me pueden ayudar dándome una luz de porque llega el valor null al servlet.
De antemano mil gracias

Comment: Ya lograste arreglar el error?